# qtscript engine - make system calls

Tags: qt, qtscript

I use qtscript in an application to provide automation capabilities for various functions within the application.

To allow greater flexibility i need the possibility to execute other tools (commandline commands/applications) from the script and get their output (the application itself is not security relevant - so calling random code may be ok).

Is their a way to do this with the basic qtscript module or some 3rd party class that encapsulate this or do i have to do this on my own?

Comment: You have to do it yourself, but it is not that difficult using QProcess wrapper. See related discussion: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/35725-Using-QProcess-in-QtScript

Comment: @Archie thanks that helped and its working now. the `QProcess` hint helped me a lot. may be post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process can be spawned via [QProcess](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qprocess.html) class. It also provides console I/O capabilities to fetch executed process output (standard and error).

You will need to have a wrapper class however, since QProcess cannot be exposed directly to script environment (e.g. it defines no public slots accessible to a script).

See [Related discussion](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/35725-Using-QProcess-in-QtScript) on qtcentre forum.